# How do I get Django values_list to return value of display override and not the actual value?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

I noticed that when calling `values()` or `values_list()` one a queryset returns the normal value in the field and not the display value I'd like. Is there a way to manupilate the display value of the field while creating a result that is a list of list of the queryset?

```py
class FooBar(models.Model):
    ...
    foo_bar = models.CharField(_("foo"),  choices=[(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')])

    def get_foo_bar_display(self):
        return "something"

def get_foobar(user):
    foobar = FooBar.objects.filter(user=user).values_list(.., 'foo_bar')
    foobar = list(map(list, foobar))
    return foobar
```

It always returns the foo_bar original value and not the display value.

Comment: The display value is never stored in the database, so since you use a list and not a model object, it can not perform any mapping.

Comment: This is one (of the many) reasons why using `.values`/`.values_list` is often not a good idea.

Comment: What would be the alternative? At the moment I'm using the values_list method in an async view that returns JSONReponse for the ajax calls to populate a datatable

Comment: working with serializers https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way out for you is to get the model instances with only some selected fields (needed for the `get_x_display` to work correctly) using `.only()` query set method.

Going from there you can call the `get_x_display` on the model like you'd normally do.

Comment: Oh man I completely missed `.only()` this is a perfect solution along side using the serializers method.